# Resizing Slidder using css

Tags: html, css

I want to keep the size of my images in my slider but i would also like to reduce the large space between my slider and my menu bar. This is being a real tool and i would appreciate it if someone guided me in the right direction. My slider leaves a huge gap between itself and the menu bar. Do i resize the image in photoshop and then place it in the slider or is there any other way around this?

Here is a [Demo](http://jsbin.com/cuvumoreze/1/edit?html,css,output)

Here is my css

```
  div#slider { 
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
   margin: 25px auto -52px;

   }
        div#slider figure img { 
        width: 20%; 
        float: left;
        margin: 25px auto -52px; 
         }
  `            
        @-webkit-keyframes slidy {
        0% { left: 0%; }
        20% { left: 0%; }
        25% { left: -100%; }
        45% { left: -100%; }
        50% { left: -200%; }
        70% { left: -200%; }
        75% { left: -300%; }
        95% { left: -300%; }
        100% { left: -200%; }
         }




   div#slider figure { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 500%;
   margin: 0;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: 30s slidy ease-in-out infinite;
   animation: 30s slidy ease-in-out infinite;   
   margin: 25px auto -52px;
   }`div#slider figure { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 500%;
   margin: 0;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: 30s slidy ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: 30s slidy ease-in-out infinite; 
  margin: 25px auto -52px;
   }


#header {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 940px;
}
#navigation {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 26px;
  margin-left: -1.0416667%; 
  padding-right: 1.0416667%; 
  padding-left: 1.0416667%; 
  width: 97.9166667%; 
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-bottom-color: #bfbfbf;
  border-bottom-style: double; border-bottom-width: 4px;
}
#navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#navigation ul li a {
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial, "Lucida Grande", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img src="images/reciepescover.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/history_chocolate.jpg" alt=""> 
        <img src="images/cocoa.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/lays.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/cocoa.jpg" alt="">
    </figure>
</div>
<center>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/history.html">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/producers.html">Producers</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/companies.html">Companies</a></li>
                <li><a href="pages/reciepes.html">Reciepes </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit image using Photoshop with equal height. Or it can be done in html by using eg `height="500px";`

```
  <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ankor-wat.jpg" height="500px" alt="">
```

Provide `height` tag for all images.

Comment: My image looks super stretched. isn't there a way to decrease the slider window without the image looking strecthed?

Comment: Just change `height="500px" ` to 550px or 590px etc

Comment: I think `height="750px"` is best .

Comment: Do i change the height in the #slider css or my image height?

Comment: In html file `<img>` tag

Answer (score -1):

Your demo link doesn't display the header banner image.  You should fix this so it is easier to see what you are trying to do.  Makes it easier to give you an answer.

Also, just fyi, in your css, you do not need to, nor shouldn't qualify your #id selector for the slider. `div#slider`.

`#slider` works just fine.

Comment: Ahh once again love a down vote for trying to get the info to help fix the issue. Thanks guys!